# Async - await , как внутри работает асинхронный код?

Tags: c#, async-await, асинхронность

Есть такое понятие "Асинхронное программирование", которое подразумевает, что пока ожидается результат выполнения задачи, `C#` не блокирует основной поток, а переходит на другую задачу пока ожидаемая задача не вернёт результат.
Вопрос: как это устроено внутри? Как `C#` понимает, что задача вернула результат?

Comment: Можете почитать про машину состояний, но вообще это сложновато для начинающих, лучше в дебри сразу не лезть, а просто научиться пользоваться https://habr.com/ru/post/470830/

Comment: Есть очередь, простые функции выполняются по очереди. await прерывает выполнение функции и берет следующую из очереди. Низкоуровневые реализации асинхронщины дополнительно ещё вешают ещё события, которые цикл проверяет при каждом заходе в await. Если событие (например получение файла по сети) завершилось то возвращается в ту функцию которая его повесила.

Comment: @eri не совсем так или совсем не так. Ничего await не прерывает, всеми операциями занимается машина состояний, await всего-лишь точка раздела между одним состоянием этой машины и следующим. Вы говорите об очереди, об очереди чего? Где она лежит? Паттерн "конечный автомат" почитайте, самый простой автомат ближе к теме, чем ваш комментарий. Добавил еще один дубликат к ссылкам вверху.

Comment: @aepot программировали на чем нибудь из чего эта асинхронщина сделана, libuv?) "точка раздела между одним состоянием этой машины и следующим" - я тоже самое сказал) а про очередь разберем пример. новое подключение в сокете, один воркер... за ним сразу второе. так вот accept на втором произойдет когда функция разбора первого пакета дойдет до await. поток переключается в цикл событий и выгребает оттуда новый коннект.... а функции без событий выполняются просто по очереди падая в цикл и сразу выплняясь

Comment: @eri There's no thread (c), не думайте о потоках, когда говорите про асинхронный код. Асинхронность != многопоточность. Хотя, все это уже рассказано в ссылках-дубликатах, и не только мной. Таск сигналит окончание операции, машина идет дальше, за то, куда попадает континуация, отвечает конеткст синхронизации. Всё просто. Сигнал может прилететь от обертки над кодом в потоке, может прилететь из порта аппаратного устройства, откуда угодно. Вообще за всю асихронную операцию может быть не использовано ни одного потока, так что я пока не могу связать ваши "циклы" с реальностью.

Comment: @eri асинхронность - это про ожидания, а не про выполнение. Про выполнение - это многопоточность.

Comment: я хоть слово сказал о потоках?

Comment: про выполнение во время ожидания.